# Flutter Future StreamBuilder stuck at waiting when data is null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a `StreamBuilder` with Future function and it all works as expected with the exception when the snapshot data is `null`.

Then my `connectionState` is stuck at waiting and I am seeing endless `CircularProgressIndicator`. Instead, I'd like to display `No data`.

I assume that the snapshot is stuck in `waiting` state because of the Future function but I am not entirely sure how `StreamBuilder` is supposed to behave in this case, despite checking all documentation.

Any advice please?

```
StreamBuilder<ProductsModel>(
    stream: _postsController.stream,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ProductsModel> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {            
            //Do something    
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
                child: Text("Error"),
            );
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
)
```

);

Comment: `stream: _postsController.stream,` is likely creating a new stream on each build(), which resets the StreamBuilder to look for the *new* "first event".  Don't build the stream in the stream parameter of the StreamBuilder. https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg